# Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable:

Tags: php, laravel-5

Why do i get this error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1327
Undeclared variable: database1 (SQL: SELECT * INTO `database1`.dbo.`tablename` FROM `database2`.dbo.`tablename`
```

when copying database on same server?

Comment: You are going to need to show how you are executing this statement & state what database you are using.

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$newdatabase = 'newdatabase';
$tablename = 'users';
$olddatabase= 'existingdatabase';``
$results = DB::unprepared("CREATE TABLE $newdatabase.$tablename LIKE $olddatabase.$tablename") ;
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `$newdatabase`.`$tablename` SELECT * from `$olddatabase`.`$tablename`";
 $data = DB::insert($sql);
```